# Differences between toViewController,toSharedViewController and toModalViewController

Tags: iphone, three20

What are the differences between `toViewController`, `toSharedViewController` and `toModalViewController` when used with `TTURLMap`?

```
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
[map from:@"tt://tabBar" toSharedViewController:[TabBarController class]];
[map from:@"tt://order?waitress=(initWithWaitress:)"
   toModalViewController:[ContentController class]];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `(void)from:(NSString*)URL toViewController:(id)target` will always recreate the UIViewController from scratch and won't try to reuse an existing view controller.

So for example, if you call `TTOpenURL(@"tt://details/view/1)` twice, it will create the view controller twice.

On the other hand, if you use `(void)from:(NSString*)URL toSharedViewController:(id)target`, the `TTNaviagtor` will create the controllers in shared mode and reuse them. It's good for menus in tab bar views.

so if you call `TTOpenURL(@"tt://menu/1)` twice for a url that was created with toSharedViewController, it will reuse an existing view controller (if the controller is in the TTNavigator stack and wasn't released by a memory warning)

the last option, `(void)from:(NSString*)URL toModalViewController:(id)target` will display the view controller by pushing it without using the existing `UINavigationBar`. It's helpful if you need to  present a "send email" view, or something that already has a UINavigationBar.